# Azure BreakLease returns 409 Conflict error

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am unable to delete an Azure blob because it has an infinite lease on it.
I am now trying to break that lease using the BreakLease() method.

Here are the commands I'm executing in PowerShell:

```
$StorageAccountName = "storage account name"
$ContainerName = "container name"
$BlobName = "blob name

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Azure.Storage\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll")
$Keys = Get-AzureStorageKey -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName
$StorageAccountKey = $Keys[0].Primary
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials($StorageAccountName,$StorageAccountKey)
$CloudStorageAccount = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount($Creds, $true)
$CloudBlobClient = $CloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
$BlobContainer = $CloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference($ContainerName)
$Blob = $BlobContainer.ListBlobs() | Where{$_.Name -eq $BlobName}
$Blob.Properties
$Blob.BreakLease($(New-TimeSpan), $null, $null, $null)
```

The blob properties output is:

```
CacheControl                  :
ContentDisposition            :
ContentEncoding               :
ContentLanguage               :
Length                        : 1098437886464
ContentMD5                    :
ContentType                   : application/octet-stream
ETag                          : "0x8D33831477A9F90"
LastModified                  : 2/18/2016 7:01:09 AM +00:00
BlobType                      : PageBlob
LeaseStatus                   : Locked
LeaseState                    : Leased
LeaseDuration                 : Infinite
PageBlobSequenceNumber        :
AppendBlobCommittedBlockCount :
```

The error message on the BreakLease() method call is:

```
Exception calling "BreakLease" with "4" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict."
At line:1 char:20
+ $Blob.BreakLease($(New-TimeSpan), $null, $null, $null)
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageException
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not targeting the right type of resource. You are running the `BreakLease` method on a different type of resource and not `TypeName: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob`

I was having the same error when targeting:

```
TypeName: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageBlob
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with blobs that represent VM disks attached to VMs in Azure availability sets. If all else fails, I'm going to update my encryption script to detect if a VM is in an availability set and if it is, to use the following process:

1. Save the VM config
2. Delete the VM, but keep the disks and NIC
3. Encrypt the disk blobs (breaking the lease should no longer be needed since the VM was deleted)
4. Recreate the VM in the availability set with its recorded configuration, and attach the old NIC and the now encrypted disk blobs

HTH